# PropertyChanged event fired but property getter not called

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm having an issue where PropertyChanged event is firing, but the UI is not updating and the relevant property getter is not being called. In other SO postings, I've seen that people have this issue when nothing in the view is actually binding to the property, but I do have something bound.

Here is an example in which I'm trying to have an "Age" output update whenever a new date of birth is changed in a DatePicker. The relevant code, which I've boiled down as much as I can:

Model:

```
public class Pft {
    public DateTime Dob;
}
```

ViewModel:

```
public class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged {
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "") {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}

public class PftViewModel : ViewModelBase {
    private Pft pft;

    public DateTime Dob {
        get { return pft.Dob; }
        set {
            pft.Dob = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
            DemographicsChanged();
        }
    }

    public int Age {
        get {  // << this does not get called after NotifyPropertyChanged("Age")
            DateTime today = DateTime.Today;

            int age = today.Year - Dob.Year;

            if (Dob > today.AddYears(-age)) {
                age--;
            }

            return age;
        }
    }

    private void DemographicsChanged() {
        NotifyPropertyChanged("Age");  // << this gets called!
    }

    public PftViewModel() {
        pft = new Pft();
    }
}

public class EntryPageViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged {
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "") {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    private PftViewModel _pft;
    public PftViewModel Pft {
        get { return _pft; }
        set {
            _pft = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public EntryPageViewModel() {
        Pft = new PftViewModel();
    }
}
```

View:

```
<Page x:Class="EntryPage">
    <StackPanel>
        <DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding Pft.Dob}" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Pft.Age, Mode=OneWay}" />
    </StackPanel>
</Page>
```

View Code-Behind:

```
public partial class EntryPage : Page {
    private EntryPageViewModel viewModel;

    public EntryPage() {
        InitializeComponent();

        viewModel = new EntryPageViewModel();
        DataContext = viewModel;
    }
 }
```

Comment: That code works for me. It updates `Age` in the UI when I change `Dob`. `Mode=OneWay` is unnecessary on `TextBlock.Text`, by the way. You only need it on `Run.Text`.

Comment: It works for me as well.

Comment: @JssDWt He's using `CallerMemberNameAttribute`, it's fine. The case where he needs to specify that parameter is the call for `"Age"` in `DemographicsChanged()`, where he does pass it.

Comment: @EdPlunkett Hmm, thanks. Something else I cut out to try to simplify the code here must be mucking it up.

Comment: @AndrewEwert That's my guess. But now it's easy: Just add stuff back in until it breaks.